# How can I sync my MSSQL database to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization

I am using MSSQL as my transactional database. This database has 200+ tables with about 25 tables that hold 1M plus records. I want to replicate the data with the same structure into a MySql database for reporting. Is there a tool or method that can do this in a fairly real time manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SQL Server's Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to access MySQL from SQL Server.

Comment: I forgot mention the functionality is free, incorporated into SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, but, I am trying to use MSSQL for my transactional database and MySql fro my reporting database. I want to move data from MS-SQL to MySql not access MySql with MS-SQL

Comment: @Jamey McElveen: You misunderstand - that only depends on the permissions of the account you are connecting to MySQL (from SQL Server) as - if the account has appropriate permission, you can insert/update/delete data on the MySQL instance via SQL Server.